# What are the equilibrium point of this coupled ODE?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Consider $$\dot x = x(a - bx - cy)$$
$$\dot y = y(-d + ex - fy)$$

$$a,b,c,d,e >0, f \geq 0$$

> Find all the equilibrium points in the set $\mathbb{R}^2_{\geq 0}$

I can find by inspection the equilibrium points

$A = (0,0)$

and

$B = (\dfrac{a}{b}, 0)$

Are there any more that can be found?

Comment: You need to solve each of four systems of linear equations: $x=0,y=0; x=0,-d+ex-fy=0;y=0,a-bx-cy=0;a-bx-cy=0,-d+ex-fy=0$. You get these by considering all the possible ways for one factor in each of $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ to be zero. For generic values of $a,b,c,d,e,f$, you'll have four equilibria, but for certain values you will have fewer or more. Of course these may not satisfy your sign constraints. For instance one of the solutions you "missed" is $(0,-d/f)$ but this is not in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve $0 = x(a - bx - cy)$ and $0 = y(-d + ex - fy)$  for the non-zero solutions $x \ne 0, y \ne 0$ you have to solve $(a - bx - cy) = 0$ and $(-d + ex - fy)$. This is two equations in two unknowns so you can solve for $x, y$ (in fact they are the equations of two lines and you are looking for their intersection). But yes, you have to go through all the solutions systematically.